# Synchronize sound effect with other Timer actions

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have this Timer that is supposed to initiate various actions at 1 second intervals. It's a pretty simple idea that simulates a 5 second countdown (literally). At the start, a JLabel is updated to set its text to "5". Simultaneously, a little mp3 sound file plays that voices the number that the user sees on the screen. Then, one second later, the text is changed to "4" and a different mp3 plays that voices the number 4. And so on until we get to zero.

This all works, but I can't get the visual updating to synchronize precisely with the audio part. The mp3 always seems to play just slightly before the screen is updated. At first, I thought that I just needed to put a little extra silence at the beginning of each mp3 on a trial and error basis until things synched up. But no matter how much silence I prepend to each mp3, I still hear the audio before the screen updates. All that changes is the lag between each "one second" update.

Anyway, here is the code that I am working with. Can anyone help me get this to synchronize? Maybe I need a second timer? I'm not sure how that would work. Thanks in advance!

```
class Countdown extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Timer countdownTimer = new Timer(1000, this);
    int countdownSeconds;
    MyJFrame myFrame;

    public Countdown(MyJFrame thisFrame) {

        int countdownSeconds = 5;
        countdownTimer.start();
        myFrame = thisFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (countdownSeconds == 0) {
                myFrame.updateCountdown(myFrame, "Go");
                SoundEffect.play("launch.mp3");
                countdownTimer.stop();
            } else {
                myFrame.updateCountdown(myFrame, Integer.toString(countdownSeconds));
                if (countdownSeconds == 5) {SoundEffect.play("five.mp3");}
                if (countdownSeconds == 4) {SoundEffect.play("four.mp3");}
                if (countdownSeconds == 3) {SoundEffect.play("three.mp3");}
                if (countdownSeconds == 2) {SoundEffect.play("two.mp3");}
                if (countdownSeconds == 1) {SoundEffect.play("one.mp3");}
                countdownSeconds--;
            }
        }
    }

public void updateCountdown(MyJFrame thisFrame, String numSec) {
    lblCountdown.setText(numSec);
}



import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class SoundEffect {

    public static void play(String mp3File) {
        try {
            FileInputStream mp3_file = new FileInputStream(mp3File);
            Player mp3 = new Player(mp3_file);
            mp3.play();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt you will ever be able to sync those perfectly, but I can explain why the current approach will not work.

Swing components must be updated on the *Event Dispatch Thread*, as you do with the `Timer`. When you update the text of the label, it will schedule a repaint on the *Event Dispatch Thread*. Note the word *schedule*, and not *perform*.

However, the *Event Dispatch Thread* is currently busy playing your sound, so the actual `repaint` operation will only occur after you called `mp3.play()`.

Now you could (if allowed, not sure about the threading rules for playing MP3's) try to play the mp3 on a different `Thread` (e.g. by using a secondary non-Swing timer). But since you never have full control over when the actual repaint is going to happen and only can control when the repaint is scheduled, the visual and auditive updates can still be out-of-sync.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that that might be the answer. It seem weird that I can't add 1 or 2 tenths of a second of silence to the start of the mp3 to make it seem as if they are synchronized. But I get your point. I think that I'll just take out the sounds and not torture myself any further. Thanks!

Comment: @usr55410 are you certain the `mp3.play()` returns before the mp3 is finished playing. If not, that would explain why you can't add any silence before it

Comment: *"doubt you will ever be able to sync those perfectly"*  This can be done using [Java Sound](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) which can provide the progress down to 1000ths of a second.  This OP seems to be using the JMF Player which ..can get the time down to [nanoseconds](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Clock.html#getMediaNanoseconds%28%29).

Comment: @AndrewThompson even if you only know when the `repaint` is scheduled and not when it is actually performed ?

Comment: So long as the repaint is called in a timely fashion and the EDT is not blocked, it should only be microseconds between being called and a paint done.  I doubt that would lead to a perception of 'lag' by the user.  Unfortunately it is a little tricky to set up code to test that theory.

Comment: After looking more closely at the code, I suspect the real problem is 'file I/O'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson agree! (didn't try it, though)

Comment: @kleopatra  Neither did I.  But I was thinking of this machine, where I configure the drives to power-down after a few minutes of inactivity.  Even when they are powered up, they are not especially fast.

Answer (score 1):

The major part of the problem comes down to:

```
if (countdownSeconds == 5) {SoundEffect.play("five.mp3");}
```

..leading to..

```
public class SoundEffect {

    public static void play(String mp3File) {
        try {
            FileInputStream mp3_file = new FileInputStream(mp3File);
            Player mp3 = new Player(mp3_file);
            mp3.play();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Whoa!  This is not the time to be ***loading*** the clips!

Instead they should be loaded before the timer ever starts.  I think the file I/O is the **real** cause of the (perceptible) lag or delay.